# Where are results of Make Query Layer?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, query-layer, python-window

I'm using **MakeQueryLayer** to create a view from a database table in the ArcMap python window. The command completes successfully but I can't see the result. Where does it go?

```
arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(r'Database Connections\Connection to database.sde',
'csw_test','select * from REPORT_TBL',"OBJECTID (Long Integer, Not nullable)")
<Result 'csw_test'>
```

Nothing shows up in table of contents, List by Source is active, changing panes and forcing a refresh has no effect. Using AddTableView doesn't work:

```
arcpy.mapping.AddTableView('Layers','csw_test')
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 113, in AddTableView
    assert isinstance(data_frame, DataFrame)
AssertionError
```

[image: Python window results]

Comment: A query table is like a query layer. It's just a rule for data access from Desktop/arcpy. There is no table created, so it doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: You can persist the View using arcpy.CopyRows_management() to any supported Table format.

Comment: @klewis `ERROR 000732: Input Rows: Dataset csw_test does not exist or is not supported`

Comment: @Vince that doesn't make sense to me. If there is nothing created then there's no need for the tool to exist at all.

Comment: It's a named query. It *exists* as an object in the document. It does not exist outside the document. If you want a persistent object, you want to use [Create Database View](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-database-view.htm).

Comment: It's the object in the document that I'm trying to locate and use! I'll try Create Database View tomorrow and see where I get to. Thanks for suggestions @vince

Comment: It's just a table object -- There isn't any geometry to appear in the ToC (unlike a Query Layer). If you want to work with it, capture the Result object

Comment: Why is the Title MakeQueryTable yet you are running MakeQueryLayer?These are two different tools.

Comment: @klewis oops. corrected. Mistake was because I've tried both tools trying to get something that works.

Comment: @vince (a) a table object should still show up in ToC "List by Source" view though. At least that's where other tables without geometry are shown; (b) capturing result gives same error, see https://i.imgur.com/uSiWrIC.png

Comment: CreateDatabaseView can't be used in this situation. The source DB is read-only.

Comment: @vince found the cause and workaround, see my updated answer (the table doesn't have a spatial column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug that's been present since 10.1 - see [Bug NIM086004](https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDg2MDA0) for status and Geonet '[Can't get reference to result from MakeQueryLayer_management](https://community.esri.com/thread/60908)' conversation for actual information. Namely: If query does not return a spatial column the resulting table does not get added to the map document.

#### Solutions

**(-)** Use ArcGIS Pro (v2.1.2+). It just works, the query view shows up as a standalone table without any other action.

**(A)** Turn off Background Processing and/or:

**(B)** `arcpy.Describe()` the result and use that object in future actions:

```
arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(
    input_database="Database Connections/Connection to our_gdb.sde", 
    out_layer_name=out_layer_name, 
    query=query, 
    oid_fields="", 
    shape_type="", 
    srid="", 
    spatial_reference="")

desc = arcpy.Describe(out_layer_name)
t = arcpy.mapping.TableView(desc.name)
arcpy.CopyRows_management(t, "myoutputtable")
```

#### Kudos

- [Tim Haverland](https://community.esri.com/people/tim.haverland_noaa) - https://community.esri.com/thread/60908#comment-287840
- [Damon Pettitt](https://community.esri.com/people/dpettittva) - https://community.esri.com/thread/60908#comment-432668

Answer (score 0):

The excellent [answer from @matt wilkie](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/302664/107424) solution worked for me but I actually needed fewer steps for what I was trying to accomplish, which was to run a query on a polygon feature class in a SQL Server database and copy the **data and shape** from the results. Here is the code which worked for me (ArcMap 10.6.1):

```
arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(
    input_database="Database Connections/Connection to our_gdb.sde", 
    out_layer_name=out_layer_name, 
    query=query, 
    oid_fields="", 
    shape_type="", 
    srid="", 
    spatial_reference="")


arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("out_layer_name", r"Path/to/file.gdb/CopyOfOutLayer")
```